# remove underline on click(function ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have Jquery function

```
  $(".Next").click(function () {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + $("#Answer").val());
        });
```

but the button Next has underline link under the text, how to get rid of the underline link ?

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS:

```css
.Next{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need a little more information to be sure. But i'm guessing .Next is the class associated to an anchor tag. If that's the case then i'm guessing you just need to add some css to the anchor. For example in a css file .Next { text-decoration:none } . For more info on css tags for anchors see : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp .

Once again for me to give you a solid answer you would need to show me the actual markup. But if it is an anchor tag you might want to also modify your code to something like this :

```
$(".Next").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of the anchor tag
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + $("#Answer").val());
        });
```

Comment: w3schools is an okay site for beginners, but should not be relied upon for more advanced knowledge, since it continues to use deprecated functions and ideas.  See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com) for more info.

Comment: thank you, but either .Next { text-decoration:none }  or e.preventDefault();  works